# Wordpress pagination links show same posts as main page why?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I am using the following code it works and gives the pagination links, unfortunately each pagination page has same content and main page why?

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3 ,'paged'=>$paged);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
while ($the_query ->have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();
 ?>
<div id="pbox">

    <div id="pthumb"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="ptitle"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'mythumbnail')); ?></a></div>
        <div id="pcontent">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="ptitle"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?><br />

Post Category: <b><?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></b>



        </div>
    </div>
<?php
endwhile;
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '/page/%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
) );
echo $paged;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: How many posts do you have?

Comment: 228 posts all together

Comment: Go to **Settings** -> **Reading** -> Change **Blog pages show at most** to 3 and see what happens.

Comment: I did that many times and changed permalink structure as well nothing works

Comment: That's weird because i tested your code on my local and it works fine.

Comment: does pagination have to be registered in functions? I am asking because I created the theme myself

Comment: No, you can put the code directly in your templates. You can try to delete all code in `index.php`, paste the code then check again to see if there're any helpful info.

Comment: tried that, this is very frustrating I see tutorials online simple on youtube and they work and I type code same as them and does not work